# how to make check box always checked until somebody changes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, checkbox

I have two check box m_chkRegex and m_chkCaseSensitive which will be checked through code shown below

```
public PropertyFilter InFilter
  {
     get{ return m_inFilter; }
     set{ m_inFilter = value; }
  }
  private PropertyFilter m_inFilter = null;
        m_operatorComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
     if( Property != null )
     {
        m_propertyLabel.Text = Property.DisplayName;
        if( InFilter != null )
        {
           m_operatorComboBox.SelectedItem = InFilter.GetOperatorAsString();
           m_valueTextBox.Text = InFilter.GetValueAsString();
           m_chkRegex.Checked = ( InFilter.FilterType == PropertyFilter.enumFilterType.regularExpr );
           m_chkCaseSensitive.Checked = InFilter.CaseSensitive;
        }
     }
```

Due to some reasons "InFilter" become null and both check box becoming unchecked. So i am desiding to put a hard rule like that once these two check boxes checked ,it should be checked until some body come and change it . In ASP.NET i heard we have IsPostBack property which will make check box checked, but do we have any mechanism in winform to acheive it.

**UPDATE**

Now i understood , following is the problem causing code  variable pFilt  become null , but i dont know what to do

```
private void LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
      {
         // Get appropriate information.
         PropertyFilter pFilt = (PropertyFilter)e.Link.LinkData;
```

Comment: why don't you just check if lnFilter is null?

Comment: Why would the property be changed if `InFilter` is `null`?  You must have some code somewhere else that's setting it to false.  Find that code and remove/fix it.

Comment: @elyashiv no we cant do that, there are some code which i hide from here and working based on that. So i cant think of making it = null

Comment: okey that will do later, but for a work around ,do we have any code which will remain check box checked after checking it

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk i updated Infilter

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're not testing for the right thing. Your code should look like this (if I get where you're going with this).

```
private PropertyFilter m_inFilter = null;
if( m_inFilter != null )
{
     //CheckBox logic.
}
```

I'm sure your know that this is the `CheckBox` syntax : `CheckBox.Checked(bool);`
So the logic thing here would be to check (with a breakpoint) why

```
InFilter.FilterType == PropertyFilter.enumFilterType.regularExpr  

//And

InFilter.CaseSensitive
```

both returns `false`. (Implying you're not testing with the wrong thing. `InFilter` instead of `m_inFilter`).

Comment: I don't see the point of your update. Did you try changing the name of the variable in your `if` test ? What does the LinkedClicked method has to do with this ?